# ICS file - edit in Notepad++ to merge lines that begin with space

Tags: notepad++, ics

my ICS calendar automatically puts carriage returns in the summary field which causes other programs to truncate on import.  I've noticed that the following line to the carriage return always starts with a space.  Is there a way in notepad to search all lines beginning with space and appending to the line above?  Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

To search for all lines beginning with a space and append them to the lines above, just replace `\r\n` (that's a space after `\n`) with just a space:

[image: 1]

Note: Make sure *Extended* search mode is selected as shown above.